# callback method in jquery validation remote to get valid parameter

Tags: jquery, struts2, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation to validate my form my code is like this -

```
$('form#Register').validate({
        rules:{
            email:{
                required:true,
                email:true,
                remote:{
                    url:"CheckEmail",
                    type:"post",
                    data:{
                        email:function(){
                            return $('input#email').val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },captcha:{
            required:true,
            remote:{
                url:"CheckCaptcha",
                type:"post",
                data:{
                    captcha:function(){
                        return $('input#captcha').val();
                    }
                },success:function(data){
                    if(data.validCaptcha){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
    });
```

I am checking if the mail is already regisgtered with the application or not with action CheckEmail. and also validating captcha with action CheckCaptcha. Both of the url is hitting the same action. which have following private field.

```
public class BaseAction {
    private boolean validMail;
    private boolean validCaptcha;
    private String email;
    private String captcha;
--Getters and setters
public String checkMail(){
        UserService uService = new UserServiceImpl();
        if(uService.getUserByEmailID(getEmail())!=null){
            setValidMail(false);
        }else{
            setValidMail(true);
        }
        return success;
    }

    public String checkCaptcha(){
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        String captchaStored = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("captcha");
        logger.info(captchaStored+" = "+getCaptcha());
        if(captchaStored!=null&&captchaStored.equals(getCaptcha())){
            setValidMail(true);
        }else{
            setValidMail(false);
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

the problem is jquery validation only expect a value true or false in response but my action gives a response like this -

```
{"captcha":null,"email":"admin@ba.co","validCaptcha":false,"validMail":true}
```

I think it's struts action's default behaviour to return value of all the private property.

Now the question is -

1. Is there any way to tell struts action i want only value of valid
   captcha or validMail as true or false. or
2. Is there any callback function in jquery validation so that i can further process the response data and can check mail or captcha
   validity myself and tell validator it's valid or invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Do not do this client-side...

```
success: function(data){
    if(data.validCaptcha){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

... because that's already handled internally by the plugin.

You're just supposed to output `"false"` (also `undefined`, `null`, or a string) for invalid or `"true"` for valid from your server-side script and `remote` will capture & handle the response automatically.

[Documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/):

> The **serverside** resource is called via jQuery.ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and
>   gets a key/value pair corresponding to the name of the validated
>   element and its value as a GET parameter. The **response** is evaluated as
>   JSON and must be `true` for valid elements, and can be any `false`,
>   `undefined` or `null` for invalid elements, using the default message; or
>   a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead" to
>   display as the error message.

You also do not need the `data` parameter...

```
data:{
    captcha:function(){
        return $('input#captcha').val();
    }
}
```

... because the value of the `#captcha` field is already being sent to your server-side script by `remote`.  The `data` parameter is only used if you need to send *additional* data along with this request.  Please refer to [this example in the docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/#example:-makes-the-email-field-required-an-email-and-does-a-remote-request-to-check-if-the-given-address-is-already-taken-in-addition-the-http-method-is-set-to-%E2%80%9Cpost%E2%80%9D-and-the-username-is-sent-alongside-the-email-address).

---

This should be all you need...

```
captcha: {
    required: true,
    remote: {
        url: "CheckCaptcha",
        type: "post"
    }
}
```

---

**Quote OP**:

> *"Is there any callback function in jquery validation so that i can further process the response data and can check mail or captcha validity myself and tell validator it's valid or invalid."*

There's no reason to do that.

- If the response from the server is `true`, you're telling jQuery Validate the field is "valid".
- If the response from the server is `false`, `null`, `undefined` or a string, you're telling jQuery Validate the field is "invalid".  If you return a string, it must be JSON formatted and it will become the error message.

You need to fix your server-side code so that it conforms to this requirement.  Otherwise, you cannot use the jQuery Validate plugin.

---

**Quote OP**:

> *"Is there any way to tell struts action i want only value of valid captcha or validMail as true or false."*

I'm no Struts expert, but instead of `return success`, have you tried `return true` and `return false` in your server side code?  Do the logic in your Struts action and return the appropriate boolean.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my question this answer only says what i got in the documentation or over internet it doesn't answer my question

Comment: @RaviKumar, I guess you don't really understand my answer or the documentation because the code in your OP is wrong and I explained that clearly.  **You do not need the `data` or `success` parameters and your server side script *must* return a boolean or JSON string.**  Until you make these modifications, your code will fail.

Answer (score 0):

remote:false

remote error message works with when remote is false only.

The above statement will work. It means when remote get false as response then it will show error message.
For example: While checking email unique identity if email already exist then return false why because the entered email not available for new user. if email not exist in database means available for new user  return true why because the user name available at this time it won't show error message.

if( checkEmailAvailable(String email) )
{

//If email already exist i.e not available

return false;
}

else

{

return true;

}